# How to pass an object to a MVC controller via Jquery Ajax Get

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am new to jquery and I can't resolve the following problem : I want to pass an object to one of the controllers in my mvc application. Here is what I got so far:

```
function enterPressed() {
    $(function () {
        $('#textBox').keypress(function (e) {

            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (code == 13) {
                doSomethingElse(textBox.value)

            }
        });
    });
}

function doSomethingElse(p) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {string: p},
        url: '"Control/AddControl/Index"',
        success: function (data) { alert(p) },
        error: function (errorData) { alert("fail") }
    });
    return true;
```

But every time when I press enter I end up with the fail. My controller is found in ~/Controllers/Control/AddControl. Do any of you see the problem ?

My C# code:

```
  public class AddControlController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AddControl/


    public ActionResult Index(string control)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ShowControl");
    }
}
```

Comment: your url is /AddControl/Index

Comment: _"I end up with the fail"_ - that is because you are ignoring the `errorData`. Do you want us to guess the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change value name to `control`, as action expected. Also you can use `@Url.Action()` helper for setting `url` param.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { control : p},
        url: '@Url.Action("Index","AddControl")',
        success: function (data) { alert(p) },
        error: function (errorData) { alert("fail") }
    });
```

Finally, your action can't return redirect action with ajax response.
If you want to make redirect after successful response, you can make it in client side.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

1-you are using a wrong url. The correct url is '/AddControl/Index'.

2-Your code in your controller won't work, since you are using ajax. You should return Json and handle the redirect in the client side.

3-You should allow GET through ajax:

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{
   return Json("Ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just `POST` in stead of `GET`.

```
function doSomethingElse(p) {
    $.post(
        '@Url.Action("Index", "AddControl")',
        {
            control: p
        },
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
}
```

You should decorate your controller action with the `HttpPost` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string control)
{
    return Json("I received this: " + control);
}
```